# Java datastructure to map multiple keys to the same value

Tags: java, data-structures

In Java I'm looking for a way to map multiple keys to the same value. Let's say I have the numbers 0-9 as keys, and "x", "y" and "z" as values as follows:

```
0->y
1->y
2->y
3->x
4->x
5->y
6->z
7->y
8->z
9->z
```

now x,y and z are really long strings, and I have millions of keys so I can't afford to store the strings multiple times. How would you go about it?

One idea I had was to create two arrays: an artificial second to key is generated to which the original keys are mapped and which in another array is the key to the actual values. That way the values are only stored once and the original keys can still be indirectly mapped to the values:

```
0->k1
1->k1
2->k1
3->k2
4->k2
5->k1
6->k3
7->k1
8->k3
9->k3

k1->y
k2->x
k3->z
```

Question though: Is there a better data structure for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any `Map<Integer,String>` will do - you are only storing a reference to the string, not a copy of it, so it doesn't matter how long it is.

If you are building the same string value multiple times, use `intern()` to get the same String object for the value each time.

Comment: Pete, fair enough. I don't really have time to write a paper on it so I've just deleted the comment.

Comment: Definitely a correct answer, but wouldn't it be nice to not have to `map.put(k,v)` for repeating values? It would be nice to do something like `map.put(k1, k2, ... , kn, v)`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the question.  If you have an array of Strings: `String[] arr` then just set different indices to the same object - aka make the references the same.

```
String[] map = new String[10];
String x = "foo";
String y = "bar";
String z = "baz";
map[0] = x;
map[1] = y;
map[2] = x;
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not invert the key/value pairing?  Use a Set or array for the values:

```
x->{3, 4}
y->{0, 1, 2, 5, 7}
z->{6, 8, 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like Pete Kirkham's suggestion (which would be the best way, IMO), you could use a Google Collections (er... [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) now) [`MultiMap`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Comment: I was going to suggest MultiMap as well but he is looking for multiple keys mapping to the same value rather than the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Each map entry will use several hundred bits to represent a value that theoretically could be kept in 2.

If the keys are more dense than some number on the order of 1 every several hundred integers, it will be faster and smaller to not using a map at all, but an array - something like a [Trove TByteArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TByteArrayList.html) - where byte values are mapped to your strings.  If you want to get 4x more density, pack 4 values into a single byte.

This only makes sense to bother with when you've got a lot of data - but you said millions of keys, so I think it's a good fit.

Answer (score -1):

Java will automatically consolidate String references for you, so you don't need to do it manually in order to save memory. You can just put the keys / values in a HashMap.

Comment: That's not true.  If it's a literal, the compiler will intern the Strings so that equal literals are replaced by the same String object, and you can manually call `intern()`, but Java will never implicitly/automatically do any of this at runtime.  Once you have a reference to a String Java won't change that reference to point to some other behind the scenes, and you can always have unique instances of the same string using the `new` keyword.  So none of that happens for Strings read from an input stream or user input, for example.